# htaccess rewrite, how to do this?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say I have a list of links in a folder, for example:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subfolderfolder/hello-one.php
http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subfolderfolder/hello-two.php
http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subfolderfolder/hello-apple.php
http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subfolderfolder/hello-pear.php
http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subfolderfolder/hello-orange.php
http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subfolderfolder/hello-six.php
http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subfolderfolder/hello-banana.php
```

and I wanted them to look like:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subfolderfolder/hello-one/
http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subfolderfolder/hello-two/
```

and so on..

How would I go about doing it? I only want it done for this folder, for the php files inside it, without doing a rule for each page, can it be done globally for all php files in this folder?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

Assuming that you want to do this for this folder only

```
RewriteRule http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subfolderfolder/(/*)$ 
http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subfolderfolder/$1.php
```

The above code will be in one line, I have put on second line for visibility

You can also checkout this tutorial http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: This will not work. Changing (/*)$ to something like (.*)$ might work, but its not the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This will allow you to access http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/home-one.php as http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/home-one

There are other rules you can create which can setup redirects so that old links will be forced to use the new ones. Just google the issue there are lots of tutorials and help out there. This is one I found - http://www.sicanstudios.com/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/